# Modification to core files

Tags: custom, enterprise-1.14, profiler

A developer modified some of our core magento files... not sure I trust the code... Our profiler is saying "mage::dispatch::routers_match" and "mage::dispatch::controller::action::predispatch" are taking 10 and 6 seconds respectively. The code was modified as below:

```
public function dispatch()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    // If pre-configured, check equality of base URL and requested URL
    $this->_checkBaseUrl($request);

    $request->setPathInfo()->setDispatched(false);

    $this->_getRequestRewriteController()->rewrite();

    Varien_Profiler::start('mage::dispatch::routers_match');
    $i = 0;
    while (!$request->isDispatched() && $i++ < 100) {
        foreach ($this->_routers as $router) {
            /** @var $router Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract */
            if ($router->match($request)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    Varien_Profiler::stop('mage::dispatch::routers_match');
    if ($i>100) {
        Mage::throwException('Front controller reached 100 router match iterations');
    }
    // This event gives possibility to launch something before sending output (allow cookie setting)
    Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_front_send_response_before', array('front'=>$this));
    Varien_Profiler::start('mage::app::dispatch::send_response');
    $this->getResponse()->sendResponse();
    Varien_Profiler::stop('mage::app::dispatch::send_response');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_front_send_response_after', array('front'=>$this));
    return $this;
}
```

Does this look ok or can the time needed for the 2 about items be explained by this code? I am sure I would need to provide more information to answer my question, let me know what else I need to send!

Thanks

Comment: can you please tell us what is the change your developer did and in which file?

Comment: Above (in my post) is the file that they modified and the original can be found here:
http://freegento.com/doc/d5/d0e/_core_2_controller_2_varien_2_front_8php-source.html